# Approximating $(1+\frac{1}{z})^z$ where $|z|$ is large

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I know that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$
Is there an equivalent in complex analysis for
$$\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^z=?$$

Comment: Yes, if you use the principal branch of the logarithm for the power. You have $$\biggl(1 + \frac{1}{z}\biggr)^z = \exp \biggl(z\log \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{z}\biggr)\biggr).$$ A little Taylor expansion gives the result.

Comment: $exp(\sum{\frac{n(-1)^{n-1}}{z^{n-1}}})$, does that mean the result is $e$, regardless of the phase on $z$ ?

Comment: You can use what @DanielFischer wrote plus the fact that $(\log (1+h))/h\to 1$ as $ h\to 0$ in $\mathbb C.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|z|\gt1$, we can use the convergent power series
$$
\log\left(1+\frac1z\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k\,z^k}\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,z\log\left(1+\frac1z\right)-1\,\right|
&=\left|\,z\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k\,z^k}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)\,z^k}\,\right|\\
&\le\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{|z|^k}\\
&=\frac1{2|z|-2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}z\log\left(1+\frac1z\right)=1\tag{3}
$$
and since $e^z$ is continuous at $z=1$,
$$
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1z\right)^{\large z}=e\tag{4}
$$